# Benchmarking gem improvements

Tags: ruby, rubygems, benchmarking

I am working to improve one of my own gems. I would like to be able to get some data on the magnitude of improvement (if any) of the various ideas I come up.

Normally I test using the benchmark/ips facility.

So I would like to load the old version of my gem and the new one for the purpose of conducting side-by-side tests.

I don't know how to load two versions of the same gem and have them apply selectively as needed.

So far my best idea is to clone the old gem, and build a local copy with an altered name like "old_gem_name". Then load that for comparison purposes.

Is there a better way?

Comment: There's usually little advantage to running two tests in the same program, vs. running the test harness twice with two different implementations of the function under test.  Separate invocations avoids effects like the 2nd one running faster because the test data is already hot in cache, or CPU frequency has time to go to max turbo, which people sometimes fail to control for.  Can't you just run with different options to control which version gets loaded?  (Unless your test setup / creation of input data is *very* slow, seems like no real downside.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this using two different Gemfiles.

So assuming you have a `benchmark.rb` file that has the following:

```
# benchmark.rb
require 'benchmark'
puts Benchmark.measure { 1000.times{ call_to_gem_method} }
```

Then with your two different Gemfiles, one called `Gemfile-oldgem` and the other called `Gemfile-newgem`, you do the following:

```
# Gemfile-oldgem
gem "mygem", :path => "/path/to/oldgem/mygem"
```

Run this for the old gem benchmark:

`BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile-oldgem bundle exec ruby benchmark.rb`

And for the new gem you have:

```
# Gemfile-newgem
gem "mygem", :path => "/path/to/newgem/mygem"
```

Run this to benchmark it:

`BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile-newgem bundle exec ruby benchmark.rb`